# URL information for simple page - parsing with PHP

Tags: php, url, get, http-status-code-404

I have a domain name and on FTP is the only one file - `index.php`. In this file are just information about my project - simple HTML.

Now I would need to set some information to URL, like

```
http://mywebsite.com/some-words
```

If in URL address would be this string, I need to get the string (`some-words`) and take a look at the array, if this string is there and based on that print some text.

But my problem is, that if I set up the address

```
http://mywebsite.com/some-words
```

to the browser, I'll got the `404` error.

How can I avoid this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only have a file at `/index.php`, you don't have anything at `/some-words`. Without any modification to the webserver, it had no way to know that you want a request against `/some-words` to be processed by `/index.php`.  Thus, you get a 404 error since the server can't find anything at `/some-words`